# trying generate user identity from cookie

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, jwt, asp.net-identity

I am trying to authenticate via cookie where I get the JWT token from a cookie and generate a user identity. However, the `AddCookie` section is not being called at all.

So when I pass a JWT token from the header, it creates an identity user. I want this feature to be available for cookies as well.

so when I pass a token in a cookie it should generate a user identity.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddSingleton<IIPAddressChecker, IPAddressChecker>();

        RsaSecurityKey publicKey = GetPublicKey();
        services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
        {
            auth.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build());
            auth.AddPolicy(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                   new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                       .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                       .Build());
        });
        services.AddLogging(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                .AddConsole()
                .AddDebug()
                .AddFile(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        });
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("ListedOrigins", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(allowOrigins)
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials()
                   .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                   .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        }));

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap["role"] = "role";
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap["name"] = "name";
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap["sub"] = "sub";
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap["email"] = "email";

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = !Configuration.GetValue("DisableHttpsRequirement", false);
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                IssuerSigningKey = publicKey,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuers = issuers,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role",
            };

        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
                {
                    string token = context.Request.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == "userJwt").Value;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                    {
                        context.RejectPrincipal();
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            IssuerSigningKey = publicKey,
                            ValidateAudience = false,
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidIssuers = issuers,
                            RequireSignedTokens = true,
                            RequireExpirationTime = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            NameClaimType = "name",
                            RoleClaimType = "role",
                        };
                        var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
                        context.Principal = principal;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        context.RejectPrincipal();
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }

            };
        });

        services.AddProxy(httpClientBuilder =>
            httpClientBuilder.ConfigureHttpClient(
                client => client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds)));
    }
```